# How to get details on procedure types in a record using rtti in Delphi

Tags: delphi, rtti

Given a Delphi record that contains procedure types as fields, for example:

```
TProcType1 = function (index : integer; value : double) : string;
TProcType2 = function (bValue : boolean; ptr : TPointer) : integer; 
TMyRecord = record
   proc1 : TProcType1;
   proc2 : TProcType2;
end
```

Is it possible to get hold of the detailed information on the procedure type signatures? eg that proc1 is declared as a procedure type with two arguments, integer and double, and a return type of string?

I can convert the procedure types field into a string using ToString on a field and parse it for the information, for example, using code such as:

```
 context := TRttiContext.Create;
 rtype := context.GetType(TypeInfo(TMyRecord));
 fields := rtype.GetFields;
 for i := 0 to High(fields) do
     begin
     astr := fields[i].FieldType.ToString;
     // parse astr to get info on procedure type
     end
```

I was wondering if there is any way to deconstruct the procedure types using rtti instead of having to manually parse to ToString? For normal method fields, this is possible.

I can guarantee that the record will only contain procedure type fields. Using Delphi 10.4

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: It's more of a curiosity at the moment but I'm exploring the idea of creating a Delphi library that exports a self-documenting C compatible API. The library exports two methods, one that returns a pointer to a record of method pointers representing the functionality in the library and a second that returns a pointer to a record of reflection methods.  The idea in my head is that when loaded, the reflection API can be used to automatically construct either a Python or a GUI interface at runtime.  Its something to play around with on a Sunday afternoon.

Comment: This is technology that already exists. Its called a type library.

Comment: What fun is there in using that? It's a Sunday afternoon, can't someone have a bit of fun?

Comment: My point was that if you were looking to make something that was widely useful then a type library would be the way to go. If you want to experiment and learn and have fun, nothing wrong with that.

Comment: It was just for fun. I’ve used com in the past, it a bit unwieldy but it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is rather straightforward:

```
var
  Context: TRttiContext;
  RType: TRttiType;
  Field: TRttiField;
  p: TRttiProcedureType;
  param: TRttiParameter;
begin
  Context := TRttiContext.Create;
  RType := Context.GetType(TypeInfo(TMyRecord));
  for Field in RType.GetFields do
  begin
    if Field.FieldType is TRttiProcedureType then
    begin
      p := TRttiProcedureType(Field.FieldType);
      Writeln(p.Name);
      Writeln('Parameter count: ', Length(p.GetParameters));
      for param in p.GetParameters do
      begin
        Writeln('Parameter name: ', param.Name);
        if Assigned(param.ParamType) then
          Writeln('Parameter type: ', param.ParamType.ToString);
      end;
      if Assigned(p.ReturnType) then
        Writeln('Result type: ', p.ReturnType.ToString);
      Writeln;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Output:

```
TProcType1
Parameter count: 2
Parameter name: index
Parameter type: Integer
Parameter name: value
Parameter type: Double
Result type: string

TProcType2
Parameter count: 2
Parameter name: bValue
Parameter type: Boolean
Parameter name: ptr
Parameter type: Pointer
Result type: Integer
```

[`TRttiParameter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TRttiParameter) also has a [`Flags`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TRttiParameter.Flags) property which is a [set](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TypInfo.TParamFlags) that tells you the kind of the parameter (e.g. `var` or `const` or `out`).

[`TRttiProcedureType`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TRttiProcedureType) can also tell you the procedure's [calling convention](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TRttiInvokableType.CallingConvention).